# Grails 3 Taglib: cannot resolve symbol in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, taglib, grails-3.1

I'm using Grails 3.1.7 with IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2016.1. In the project are several custom taglibs. The tags are working as expected, but the view editor shows an error on every tag usage:

[image: IntelliJ IDEA Screenshot]

Is there a way to configure IntelliJ and/or Grails that this is correctly shown? The build in Grails tags are shown correctly and jump to source is also working.

Edit 1:
On some tag there is a message that the that is not allowed here, but jump to source is also not working

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the gradle window, click "Refresh all Gradle Projects" - This usually helps resolve anything that's not found.

Also check out 2016.2 EAP as there are Grails 3 and GORM 5 improvements.

Comment: The EAP version was no option for us because we used is in production, but now the 2016.2 was released and this version fixes the issue :)